# How do I return a custom statement after finding a duplicate in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list2=[2,8,64,16,32,4,16,8]
len(set(list2)) !=len(list2)
```

I was able to use this code and received a "True" statement. How can I modify this statement to say something like "This list contains a duplicate?"

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add if else.

```
if len(set(list2)) !=len(list2): 
    print 'Contain duplicates'
else:
    print 'No duplicates'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use *if*:

```
list2=[2,8,64,16,32,4,16,8]
if len(set(list2)) != len(list2):
     print "List has duplicate"
```